# Did Russian scientists manage to remove black skin from a man?

Tags: biology, dermatology

I noticed a clickbait article around facebook; [A Russian Laboratory Has Invented A Way To Remove The Black Skin Layer Of Black People](http://likes.com/g/18895568?utm_campaign=ml&v=g8pXkP30bcGIEEXxgpDlndf41AJvBR0pS5K242&utm_medium=ml&utm_source=ml250&utm_term=5094121FHDDFDIM&page=1) .

Evidently these things have to be taken with a massive ammount of NaCl on the side, but the images depicted do appear to be real (but it's possible they are of a different activity).

Since this kind of websites is fairly hard to navigate without an adblocker, I'll leave the text portion below:

> Multiple websites have relayed information, citing Moscow News as the source. These media outlets are reporting that a Russian laboratory have invented a way to remove the "black skin" layer on Africans.
>
> In addition to the health risks associated with this new controversial procedure, some believe that thousands of immigrants are trying to integrate into Russia by matching the skin color of the local people.
>
> The process to remove the black is fairly simple. The patient soaks in a mixture of oxytane and benzadiazepine for approximately six hours before the layer is peeled off. What will they think of next?!

Comment: http://www.snopes.com/russian-laboratory-black-skin/

Comment: Those pictures amount to nothing: some 'funny' stuff on a beach chair, an extremely low-quality pic of a small part of sun-burnt skin being peeled off, and a stolen stock photo from a cosmetics site.

Comment: Do either of you want to turn these pseudo answers into real answers?

Comment: The picture shown does not look like any kind of medical or scientific procedure. Note the garden furniture, casual dress, and handy can of beer.

Comment: OK, the image is a bit disturbing.